# [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\test']

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I can not create any directories in the c://windows path.
I really want to know why I can't create any directories and how can I deal with this problem.

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.mkdir('C:\\Windows\\test', (err, data) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

and this is the error I get: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\test']

Comment: You need administrative permissions. Either start the Node server as admin, or request the permissions within the script (by calling UAC for instance)

Comment: It works now. but how can i change permission in my script..